# Can I create a hybrid bot using dialogflow and messenger?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, chatbot, facebook-messenger

So i have been using dialogflow for a while now and I have always faced the problem of not being able to create a "Talk to human" button or somesort of an intent or function that makes the bot stop responding for the user while a real human could chat with the user and when they are done the bot could run back as normal.
The issue is I can only find it in things like https://Respond.io or other platforms that is paid and sort of overpriced.
I always wondered if there is a way to recreate what they actually do in any way by my own? wether it is by something inside dialogflow it self or by creating another website that sends an order or something to dialogflow? I can see how it would work if it was a website chatbot where i will just make a button that entirelly redirects the user or just turns off the user out of the sight of the bot untill they are done , but on messenger I cant find something for it nor searching for it helped.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Is my understanding correct that you want a human to respond on the other side while user is talking to bot?

Comment: i want the user to be able to change from bot to live chat

Comment: Could you please provide an example of existing bot that does it?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [link](https://github.com/dialogflow/agent-human-handoff-nodejs)

Comment: I want something like tge following 
user sends a message with hi bot responds and the flow goes on untill user says i want to chat with a real person .  so the bot responds for sure and then the bot turns off . now whatever the user says the bot wont respond untill the stuff member who responded to the user clicks a button or something that turns the bot on again .
this should be user specific so the bot is off for this user only not affecting all other users .

Comment: Gray-Rhino  yes exactly but for messenger not a web interface , is that possible?